# Save file and images in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, windows

I saves word files and images as a `varbinary` type in SQL Server by using this code:

Files:

```
byte[] data = null;

FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(newfile);
long numBytes = fInfo.Length;

FileStream fStream = new FileStream(newfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fStream);
data = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);

return data;
```

and images:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(ms, format);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    return base64String;
}
```

But they use a large volume in table and so the backup file of database has a large size.

What can I do for saving them with low volume?

Comment: For most use cases, it's advised to store files on the file system, not in the database. In the database you only need to store a pointer (path) to where the file is located.

Comment: Then do not store the file bytes in that table but just the path where you can retrieve the file on your file system. (This however doesn't save you anything from your total backup size)

Comment: Have a look into Filestream https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/

Comment: when I save path of the file , this path become wrong for the other users with different computers because they dont have that file in their pc

Comment: FileTables is realy good solution for that - [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server)

Comment: Don't store the files on the User's PC. Save the files on a File Share, on a location that everyone (or those that need to) can access. Either way, if you're going to be storing the files on SQL Server or a File Share, then that data needs to be stored somewhere. You can't expect to create 10,000 1MB files, and  expect your database size to be less than ~10GB. The files will take up the space they are; and your Back up is going to be large (they always are for files).

Answer (score 2):

You can store binary files in a folder on the server, but this time you might have problem with backup and restore operations and synchronizing database file data and data folder files.

To store data in database manages and removes these complexity 
And even with SQL Server 2012 we have a table type, [FileTable](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/save-image-to-database-table-in-sql-server.aspx)
You can try to use FileStream feature of SQL Server and make it easier to manage file transactions, by simple copy paste or delete operations of file folder, etc.
So by just like saving a file to a folder on the server, you directly insert file data into FileTable.
Of course your database size again increases but this is more convenient.